# How can I make sense out of ibdata

Tags: mysql, database

I've made a stupid mistake of backing up the wrong database for the whole time, and an accident just happened leaving my entire database destroyed. The only thing that I have is an ibdata1 file, I am just wondering if there are any tools that can allow me to make more sense out of an ibdata file to do as much recovery as possible? This is just a personal project so it's not necessary to get everything back. I just hope that I can get as much back as I can and it seems like ibdata1 contains some info that I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is enough for an answer to the question, but the go-to dudes for mysql tools are percona, and they have a innodb recovery toolkit;
http://www.percona.com/software/mysql-innodb-data-recovery-tools/

This page from the manual indicates that direct recovery of the data from the ibdata1 file is possible, if quite an involved manual process;
http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/innodb-data-recovery-tool:mysql-data-recovery:extracting_the_desired_pages

Comment: if you are deeply in the mire, i think they will recover it for you http://www.percona.com/mysql-consulting/data-recovery/ (haha, I don't work for percona or anything, I just think their stuff is very cool)

Comment: Hahah, not yet willing to shell out a huge amounts for the recovery, so I'll give it a try myself first. But thanks for the heads up!